# TABULATOR - Mutator not displaying data

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, tabulator

I have a problem with a mutator not displaying data. I have five columns getting the data from an AJAX URL (and those work fine), and I have a sixth column in which I intend to get data from another URL with FETCH and display it with a mutator. Here is the code for fetching the data:

```js
const comtot = async function (value, data) {
    let response = await fetch(API_TOT);
    let com = await response.json();

    console.log(com[0].total);
    return com[0].total;
}
```

And here is the code for the column with the mutator:

```js
{
    title: "Cantidad de Compras",
    field: "total",
    align: "center",
    sorter: "number",
    headerFilter: "input",
    mutator: comtot().then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        return res
    })     
}
```

I already tried using promises instead of ASYNC AWAIT and had the same result. Also, I also tried upgrading to version 4.5.3 as I saw that on a different post with a problem quite similar to mine and also didn't work.
I might add that I can log the data to the console, but not display it to the table.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Mutators in Tabulator are synchronous, they return straight away so the table dosnt have to wait for thousands of promises to resolve before it loads table data as this would dramatically increase table load times.

This means you cannot use asynchronous code like promises or await statements inside a mutator.

The correct approach would be make all these calls before you load your data into the table, and then load the finished data set in with the ***setData*** function

Answer (score 0):

*This is the same answer for another question I posted. I didn't know what was wrong with my code so I posted two different questions for two things I thought were unrelated but i was wrong.

I figured it out, the problem was that in Tabulator, the mutator in the table was getting the data from another source than the one for the rest of the table, so the table was already built when the mutator started working, and what I figured out is that the mutator needs the data ASAP when it's fired, but it's source data wasn't ready yet, so what I did was to use:

```
function delayIt() {table.setData(API_URL)}
setTimeout(delayIt, 1000)
```

so the data from the mutator source was already available when the table was built so when the mutator was fired it all worked just fine. I'm sorry if it's confusing, I couldn't figure out how to explain other way.